# Do the two coils in electomagnetic induction repel each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I have two coil A and B. Coil A has an ac current going into it and is producting a magnetic field of which is oscilating. Coil B is gaining an ac current from the fluctuating field due to Lenz's law. I wanted to verify does the two coils A and B repel each other because of the magnetic field generated?

Comment: I wanted to correct your spelling, repel instead of repeal, but edits must have a minimum change in character count.  I think that is a ridiculous rule, sometimes a single one-character change could be very important to the interpretation of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes according to Lenz's Law the induced current in always generates a field that opposes the cause. Therefore the Coils repel each other.